¿Cómo puedo quitar los días sábado y domingo de un "DatePickerDialog" en Android Studio?
Estoy creando un calendario para poder elegir una fecha, pero quiero excluir los días sábados y domingos porque esos días no estarán disponibles.
Mi código que tengo para sacar el calendario es este:
DatePickerDialog dialogo = new DatePickerDialog(this, R.style.colorCalendario, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {


            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int ano, int mes, int dia) {
                int mes2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mes));
                String mes_escrito = "";
                switch (mes)
                {
                    case 0: mes_escrito = "Enero"; break;        case 1: mes_escrito = "Febrero"; break;
                    case 2: mes_escrito = "Marzo"; break;        case 3: mes_escrito = "Abril"; break;
                    case 4: mes_escrito = "Mayo"; break;         case 5: mes_escrito = "Junio"; break;
                    case 6: mes_escrito = "Julio"; break;        case 7: mes_escrito = "Agosto"; break;
                    case 8: mes_escrito = "Septiembre"; break;   case 9: mes_escrito = "Octubre"; break;
                    case 10: mes_escrito = "Noviembre"; break;   case 11: mes_escrito = "Diciembre"; break;
                }
                texto_ver_fecha.setText(String.valueOf(ano) + "/" + mes_escrito + "/" + String.valueOf(dia));
            }
        }, ano_hoy+0, mes_hoy-1, dia_hoy+1);
        dialogo.show();

En este código incluyo también una parte para poder mostrar en un campo de texto la fecha que se eligió junto con el mes pero escrito con letras. Es funcional, pero sólo quisiera saber cómo bloquear los días sábados y domingos.
Lo único que no se vé en el código son las declaraciones de variables de:
dia_hoy = 1, mes_hoy = 0, ano_hoy = 2025;
Estos valores los uso para que, al abrir el "DatePickerDialog", se este apuntando a la fecha del día de mañana y así poder elegir una fecha cercana.

Cabe aclarar que no estoy otro código aparte de este cachito de JAVA. Tengo obviamente otros archivos .XML o .java, pero no están interviniendo en la función del "DatePickerDialog".

Quién escribe los switch así?? Los case van en línea!!

En lugar del switch , crea un array y mediante el valor de "int mes", puedes obtener la descripción del mes. En onDateSet puedes validar para no usar sábado y domingo

No existe propiedad para excluir días especificos, por lo tanto, debes usar la interfaz DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener y en onDateSet() validar las fechas que quieres descartar.
    ...
    ...
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int ano_hoy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mes_hoy = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dia_hoy = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


        DatePickerDialog dialogo = new DatePickerDialog(this, R.style.colorCalendario, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int ano, int mes, int dia) {
                Calendar selectedDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                selectedDate.set(ano, mes, dia);

                int dayOfWeek = selectedDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

                //* Validar los días no disponibles!
                if (dayOfWeek == Calendar.SATURDAY || dayOfWeek == Calendar.SUNDAY) {
                    texto_ver_fecha.setText("Sábados y domingos no son permitidos.");
                } else {
                    String[] meses = {"Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"};
                    String mes_escrito = meses[mes];
                    texto_ver_fecha.setText(ano + "/" + mes_escrito + "/" + dia);
                }
            }
        }, ano_hoy, mes_hoy, dia_hoy + 1);


        Calendar minDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        minDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        dialogo.getDatePicker().setMinDate(minDate.getTimeInMillis());

        dialogo.show();
    }
...
...

